# Cron job generates a different output compared with a controller in Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, cron, controllers, magento2.4.1

I implemented a custom plugin that loops through all products and generates a CSV file.

Even if the execute() function has the same code in both files (cron job and controller), the CSV file generated is slightly different. The controller generates the CSV as expected, but the cron job is not doing that.

For example, the controller generates a CSV file with 1000+ products, but the cron job only 400 products. The images generated by the controller are the ones that are assigned to the products, but the ones generated by the cron job are only placeholder images.

I don't know the source of these differences, but it is strange.

Are there any differences in Magento 2 between cron jobs and controllers that should be considered?

Thank you!

Comment: It will be better if you share the code that what you have done, so better help will be provided.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the main difference between running functions via cron and a controller is the `area` you are running the function. The controller is probably launched in `frontend` area and the cron job in `crontab`. The difference is that many settings depend on the area, you have many more plugins and observers in frontend area. Check `Magento\Framework\App\Area` for possible areas and check modules `etc` catalog and see that some of them have a separation for `frontend`,`adminhtml` etc.

PS there is a way to change the area, just inject via DI `Magento\Framework\App\State` class and use `setAreaCode()` function.

PS2 without the source code is hard to say so I assume that in both situations you used the same code, but I don't think that the product count should be different depending on the area, images yes, but the product count I think that should be the same

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few reasons why the output generated by a cron job in **`Magento 2.4.1`** is different from the output generated by a controller. Some potential causes include:

1. **`Differences in environment:`** Cron jobs run on the server, while
   controllers run on the client. There may be differences in the
   environment that affect the output, such as different PHP versions
   or configurations.
2. **`Differences in dependencies:`** Cron jobs and controllers may have
   different dependencies that affect the output. For example, a cron
   job may use a different database connection or configuration than a
   controller.
3. **`Differences in user context:`** Cron jobs run as the server user, while
   controllers run as the client user. This can affect the output if
   the code relies on user-specific data or permissions.
4. **`Differences in timing:`** Cron jobs are designed to run at specific
   intervals, while controllers are triggered by user requests. This
   can affect the output if the code relies on timing-specific data.
5. **`Differences in code:`** There could be code differences between the
   cron job and the controller that affect the output. For example, the
   cron job may have different function calls, different variables or
   different parameters.

Also If you can't understand so please share your code.

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**